# Is this considerably good way to insert data at given position in doubly Linked List?

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

Can this InsertAt() function  thing be done in more better way?

I am in need for good guide for computer programing who can help me improve my coding skills in
1 to 1 manner. i wrote this line  because my question was not get submitted due to too little
details ,because i had nothing more to say. **This is little anoying thing in StackOverflow**

### code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node *Head;
struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
};
//this function inserts data at head.
void Insert(char data)
{
    struct Node *tempHead = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    tempHead->data = data;
    tempHead->next = Head;
    tempHead->prev = NULL;
    if (Head != NULL)
        Head->prev = tempHead;
    Head = tempHead;
}
void Print()
{
    struct Node *tempHead = Head;
    while (tempHead != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c,", tempHead->data);
        tempHead = tempHead->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
// this function inserts at given pos .
void InsertAt(int pos)
{
    struct Node *tempHead = Head;
    struct Node *container = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    container->data = 'k';
    if (pos == 1)
    {
        Head->prev = container;
        container->prev = NULL;
        container->next = Head;
        Head = container;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++)
        {
            if (tempHead->next == NULL && i != (pos - 1))
            {
                printf("Data OverIndexed at  %d .\n",pos);
                break;
            }
            else if (tempHead->next == NULL && i == pos - 1)
            {
                tempHead->next = container;
                container->prev = tempHead;
                container->next = NULL;
                break;
            }

            else if (i == pos - 1)
            {
                struct Node *temp1 = tempHead->next;
                tempHead->next = container;
                container->prev = tempHead;
                container->next = temp1;
                temp1->prev = container;
                break;
            }

            tempHead = tempHead->next;
        }
    }
  
}

int main()
{
    Head = NULL;
    Insert('a');
    Insert('b');
    Insert('c');
    Insert('d');
    Insert('e');
    Insert('f');
      Print();
    InsertAt(1);
      Print();
    InsertAt(5);
      Print();
    InsertAt(12);
      Print();
    InsertAt(2);
      Print();
    InsertAt(20);
}
```

### output

```
f,e,d,c,b,a,
k,f,e,d,c,b,a,
k,f,e,d,k,c,b,a,
Data OverIndexed at  12 .
k,f,e,d,k,c,b,a,
k,k,f,e,d,k,c,b,a,
Data OverIndexed at  20 .
```

Comment: Hello! I would suggest you post this question over at [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Asking for 1on1 training is off topic on SO. Instead of adding unrelated stuff to your question, you could add relevant information: Why do you think there is a problem? What part don't you like and why? On SO you should ask specific question about problems. If there is no specific problem with the code, that question might be better placed next door at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: oh thankYou for giving me direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this InsertAt() function thing be done in more better way?

Yes, it can. There are several bugs in your code.

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    Head = NULL;
    InsertAt(1);
    Print();
}
```

Did it crash?

You dereference `Head` without checking for NULL here:

```
if (pos == 1)
{
    Head->prev = container;  <--- what if Head is NULL ?
```

**Another bug:**

If the function `InsertAt` is called with `pos` being `<= 0`, the function silently returns, i.e. no error printed like done when `pos` is too high.

**Yet another bug:**

In the cases where you can't insert the new element, i.e. `pos <= 0` or `pos > length-of-list`, you leak memory. You have already used `malloc` to get a new node but when the insert doesn't happen, the memory is "lost". Don't `malloc` before knowing whether you need the new node.

Besides that:

1. It's a real bad idea to use a global `Head`
2. A function that can fail (to insert the new node) should have a return value to indicate succes/failure
3. It's very strange that `InsertAt` doesn't take a `data`value (like `Insert`).

I would do something like:

```
int InsertAt(struct Node **pHead, int pos, char data)
{
    if (pos <= 0) return -1;   // Illegal pos

    if (pos == 1)
    {
        // pos == 1 is always valid
        struct Node *container = malloc(sizeof *container);
        if (container == NULL) exit(1);
        container->data = data;
        container->prev = NULL;
        container->next = *pHead;
        if (container->next != NULL) container->next->prev = container;
        *pHead = container;  // Change Head
        return 0;
    }

    if (*pHead == NULL) return -1;   // Illegal pos

    struct Node *tempHead = *pHead;
    for (int i = 1; i < (pos-1); i++)  // Notice pos-1
    {
        tempHead = tempHead->next;
        if (tempHead == NULL) return -1;  // Illegal pos
    }

    // Insert after tempHead
    struct Node *container = malloc(sizeof *container);
    if (container == NULL) exit(1);
    container->data = data;
    container->prev = tempHead;
    container->next = tempHead->next;
    tempHead->next = container;
    if (container->next != NULL) container->next->prev = container;

    return 0;
}
```

And call like:

```
struct Node *Head = NULL;
if (InsertAt(&Head, 1, 'b')) puts("InsertAt failed");
if (InsertAt(&Head, 2, 'd')) puts("InsertAt failed");
if (InsertAt(&Head, 2, 'c')) puts("InsertAt failed");
if (InsertAt(&Head, 1, 'a')) puts("InsertAt failed");
```

Comment: ,I have corrected many thing in my program ,and i am delighted to get such a  huge help from you .thank You very much , One question left is ,You have talked about function that can fail in point 2. You were trying to tell me about InsertAt() function or Insert() function?  if i am not stupidly knowledgeless to understand what you are convaying , I have kept this statement "printf("Data OverIndexed at  %d .\n",pos); " to indicate overindexing , won't it work? or Can yoou please help me one more time to understand .

Comment: @roshannepal_x `insert` can't fail (unless `malloc` fails but that's very special). I'm talking about `InsertAt` that can fail if `pos` is invalid